# span don't resize when updated by ajax text on tablet?

Tags: html, ipad, css, user-interface

Please see the screenshot

[image]

When the user clicks on the block section it get updated by an AJAX request. Every thing works fine on desktop and mobile. But on iPad2 and iPad3 it is broken.

Can any one please help?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box-block block" data-block="Block" data-unblock="Unblock" style="display: none;">
   <a data-id="2335" class="btn-box">
     <span class="blockIcn"></span>
     <span class="blockText" style="display: none;">Block</span>
   </a>
 </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
 if (block === true) {
     $box.removeClass("block");
      $box.addClass("un-block");
      $link.find('span.blockText').hide().html(unblockLabel).show();
      } else {
        $box.removeClass("un-block");
        $box.addClass("block");
         $link.find('span.blockText').html(blockLabel);
       }
```

**CSS**

```
#masonary_content .box .box-connect {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

#masonary_content .box .box-block .blockIcn  
{
    background:#1a98aa;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 4;
}

#masonary_content .box .box-block .blockText {
    background: #157381;
    padding: 14px 20px 11px 38px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 3;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Without you posting code we can run we are helpless to help you.

Comment: @DavidStorey I have added the required.